# QML Repeater with 'populate' transition

Tags: qt, qml, repeater

I am trying to replicate the `ListView.populate: Transition {..}` with a repeater. Unfortunately due to hideous performance issues I cannot simply use a `ListView`, so am restrained to the `Repeater`.

The transition I am looking for is simple, in fact exactly that used in the [ListView Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#populate-prop) which is when my repeater is loaded, each entry 'cascades' down from the top [Here is a working example of my desired outcome](https://felgo.com/web-editor/?snippet=bc8d14bc)

I have tried making us of `Behavior on y {NumberAnimation {duration: 300} }` However the repeater doesn't appear to modify the `y` on creation. I have also tied this into a `Component.onCompleted` handler to see it that triggered also but this failed.

**My Question Is**

How can I create a `y` animation similar to the `ListView.populate` property for a `Repeater`?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious alternative could be to use QML Column with a Repeater, but the Column is a positioner and will set its children y position directly without using setProperty. For this reason I made something similar, but this time letting the QML system know about the property change.

MyColumn.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QQuickItem>

class MyColumn : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(qreal spacing READ spacing WRITE setSpacing NOTIFY spacingChanged)

public:
    explicit MyColumn(QQuickItem* parent = nullptr);
    ~MyColumn();

    qreal spacing() const;
    void setSpacing(qreal r);

    void positionItems();
    void componentComplete() override;
    void itemChange(ItemChange, const ItemChangeData&) override;

Q_SIGNALS:
    void spacingChanged();

public /*slots*/:
    void onChildImplicitWidthChanged();
    void onChildImplicitHeightChanged();

private:
    qreal mSpacing;
};
```

MyColumn.cpp

```
#include "MyColumn.h"

MyColumn::MyColumn(QQuickItem* parent) : QQuickItem{ parent }, mSpacing{ 0.0 }
{
    setFlag(ItemHasContents, true);
}

MyColumn::~MyColumn()
{
}

qreal MyColumn::spacing() const
{
    return mSpacing;
}

void MyColumn::setSpacing(qreal s)
{
    if (mSpacing == s) return;
    mSpacing = s;

    Q_EMIT spacingChanged();

    if (isComponentComplete())
        positionItems();
}

void MyColumn::positionItems()
{
    qreal maxImplicitWidth = 0.0;
    qreal totalImplicitHeight = 0.0;

    QList<QQuickItem*> children = childItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.count(); ++i) {
        QQuickItem* child = children.at(i);

        //child->setY(totalImplicitHeight);
        child->setProperty("y", totalImplicitHeight);

        if (child->implicitWidth() > maxImplicitWidth)
            maxImplicitWidth = child->implicitWidth();
        if (child->implicitHeight() > 0) {
            totalImplicitHeight += child->implicitHeight();
            totalImplicitHeight += mSpacing;
        }
    }

    totalImplicitHeight -= mSpacing;

    setImplicitWidth(maxImplicitWidth);
    setImplicitHeight(totalImplicitHeight);
}

void MyColumn::componentComplete()
{
    positionItems();
    QQuickItem::componentComplete();
}

void MyColumn::onChildImplicitWidthChanged()
{
    positionItems();
}

void MyColumn::onChildImplicitHeightChanged()
{
    positionItems();
}

void MyColumn::itemChange(ItemChange change, const ItemChangeData& value)
{
    if (change == ItemChildAddedChange)
    {
        QObject::connect(value.item, &QQuickItem::implicitWidthChanged, this, &MyColumn::onChildImplicitWidthChanged);
        QObject::connect(value.item, &QQuickItem::implicitHeightChanged, this, &MyColumn::onChildImplicitHeightChanged);
    }
    else if(change == ItemChildRemovedChange)
    {
        positionItems();
    }
    QQuickItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

in main.cpp, for example, you will have to register this type a creatable type in QML

```
qmlRegisterType<MyColumn>("MyColumn", 1, 0, "MyColumn");
```

And here is the related QML code snippet:

```
//...
import MyColumn 1.0
//...
MyColumn {
    Repeater {
        model: 10
        Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 200
            implicitHeight: 30
            color: "red"
            border.width: 1
            Behavior on y { NumberAnimation { duration: 1000; easing.type: Easing.OutQuad; } }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that my implementation works with implicitWidth, but you can change this if you don't like this behavior.